# Creating files and directories via Python

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm having trouble creating a directory and then opening/creating/writing into a file in the specified directory. The reason seems unclear to me. I'm using os.mkdir() and

```
path=chap_name
print "Path : "+chap_path                       #For debugging purposes
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
temp_file=open(path+'/'+img_alt+'.jpg','w')
temp_file.write(buff)
temp_file.close()
print " ... Done"
```

I get the error

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Some Path Name'
```

Path is of the form 'Folder Name with un-escaped spaces'

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Update: I tried running the code without creating the directory

```
path=chap_name
print "Path : "+chap_path                       #For debugging purposes
temp_file=open(img_alt+'.jpg','w')
temp_file.write(buff)
temp_file.close()
print " ... Done"
```

Still get an error. Confused further.

---

Update 2:The Problem seems to be the img_alt, it contains a '/' in some cases, which makes is causing the trouble.

So I need to handle the '/'.
Is there anyway to escape the '/' or is deletion the only option?

Comment: `path+'/'+img_alt+'.jpg'` .. better to use `os.path.join()` here

Comment: @Ayos. Post the path you're working with

Comment: I don't see how `path` and `chap_path` and `img_alt` are related.

Comment: Good point @tiwo The second code snippet doesn't appear to open a file in the dir `path`

Comment: @tiwo
It *doesn't* open a file in the dir path it opens it in the current directory. Problem still persists after that.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
import os

path = chap_name

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

filename = img_alt + '.jpg'
with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as temp_file:
    temp_file.write(buff)
```

Key point is to use `os.makedirs` in place of `os.mkdir`. It is recursive, i.e. it generates all intermediate directories. See http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

Open the file in binary mode as you are storing binary (jpeg) data.

In response to **Edit 2**, if img_alt sometimes has '/' in it:

```
img_alt = os.path.basename(img_alt)
```

Comment: I understand this is the syntactically correct way of doing it, but can you actually tell me why the error occurs? And why are we using 'wb' instead of 'w' ?

Comment: The OSError is raised if the target dir to be created (the right-most directory in path) cannot be reached because a parent directory doesn't exist yet. os.mkdir is not recursive so it won't create all required directories along the path. os.makedirs does.

Comment: The 'b' is meaningful on platforms that behave different for text and binary files. To quote [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html), "Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written."

Comment: @RobCowie Do mkdir and makedirs behave differently to un-escaped spaces? And does this behaviour differ from  /usr/bin/mkdir ?

Also please check updated portion of the question.

Comment: Both handle unescaped spaces correctly. Invoking `/usr/bin/mkdir` in a shell requires you to escape spaces or quote the path string. With regard to intermediate dirs, /usr/bin/mkdir behaves like os.mkdir by default, and like os.makedirs if invoked with `-p`

Comment: ... except that `mkdir -p` succeeds when the directory already exists. Python 3.2 has `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)`, so you don't have to call `os.path.exists` and there's no race condition.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

os.mkdir('directory name') #### this command for creating directory
os.mknod('file name') #### this for creating files
os.system('touch filename') ###this is another method for creating file by using unix commands in os modules
```

Comment: Please see the original question and the accepted answer, it explicitly said that `os.mkdir` did not work, and the accepted answer pointed out that `os.mkdirs` was to be used.