# How to add a subfolder in python

Tags: python, whitelist

I am using this python script:

```
import dbg
import app
import os
def RunCheckUp():
    Whitelist = [
        'Folder1',
        'Folder2',
        ]

    path = os.getcwd()
    k = os.listdir(path)
    if k != Whitelist:
        for item in k:
            if not item in Whitelist:
                dbg.LogBox("The next file will be deleted: " + str(item))
                try:
                    os.remove(item)
                except:
                    dbg.LogBox("Delete this file " + str(item) + " pentru a putea juca.")
                    dbg.LogBox("The program will be closed.")
                    app.Abort()
            else:
                pass
    if Whitelist != k:
        for missing in Whitelist:
            if not missing in k:
                dbg.LogBox("The program can't start! This file is missing: " + str(missing))
                app.Abort()
            else:
                pass
RunCheckUp()
```

My question is how to add a file that is in the Folder2, I want do add "file1" and "file2" because I want to protect file1 and file2 from deleting not just the folder
Something like this Folder2/file1

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388368/create-file-in-sub-directory-python

Comment: Wouldn't all the files in a folder be "protected" if the folder itself is?

Comment: they are not, this just protect the name if the file is missing i get this The program can't start! This file is missing but if i ad a new file in the Folder1 directori i get this The next file will be deleted i want to do the same thing but with the files in folder2 directory

Comment: this script detect missing files or files that don't belong in some directory

Comment: I can show you how this program work does sombody have an idea how should I do this