# Repeatedly create files with counter in Python

Tags: python, text-files, python-itertools

Bascially what I want to do is writing a python script that creates files with a count-number in the filename, `"file 1.txt" "file 2.txt" "file 3.txt"` for example.

I have come this far:

```
import shutil, os, itertools


for i in itertools.count():
    file = open("FILE " + str(i) + ".txt", 'w+')
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Basically what I can do is count, but the file creation is my problem. open() doesnt seem to work.How do i create these files and how can I choose the directorys to store the files?

Comment: Do you want to create _empty_ files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating files and directories via Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700593/creating-files-and-directories-via-python)

Comment: Works on my machine.  Python 3.3  You will have to navigate to the directory you want the files created in with `os.chdir`

Comment: You could try to `close` the file within the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import shutil, os, itertools
import time

dirpath = 'c:\\usr\\'
for i in itertools.count():
    file = open(dirpath+"FILE " + str(i) + ".txt", 'w+')
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This will work. And your code works fine. I just added the directory path

Comment: Damn I only needed a path... Thanks though!!

Answer (score 3):

If you work on **Python 3.4+**, try [`pathlib.Path(...).touch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.touch),

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import itertools

for i in itertools.count():
    filename = ''.join(['FILE', str(i), '.txt'])
    Path(os.path.join(dir, filename).touch()
```

---

In **Python2**, I think using the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) is better.

```
import os
import itertools

for i in itertools.count():
    filename = ''.join(['FILE', str(i), '.txt'])
    with open(os.path.join(dir, filename), 'w'):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

number = 0
valid = False
while not valid:
    usrInput = raw_input("How much candy?: ")
    try:
        int(usrInput)
        valid = True
    except:
        print "NUMBER of candys!!"
        pass
 while number < int(usrInput):
    number +=1 
    createFile = open('P:/' + str(number) + '.txt', 'w+')
    createFile.write("whatever you want")
    createFile.close()
```

I hope this helps