# How do I create a folder through python on mac

Tags: python, macos

I have tried many things on the internet but can't find a simple code to create a folder through python on **MAC**.

Comment: does that post help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700593/creating-files-and-directories-via-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# define the name of the directory to be created
path = "/tmp/om"

try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```